# RXJS: Emit extra value based upon observable value coming in

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I am new to RxJs 6.0 (or any RxJs version for that matter) and although I see how powerful it is, some simple concepts escape me.

I have a situation where i would like to emit an extra value into the output stream based upon the source stream but for the life of me I can't figure out how to do it.  I really need a startsWith operator that can take a method instead of a static value and then I could achieve this.  Here is some silly code that sets up the scenario.

```
import { startWith, scan, tap, mergeMap, map, concat } from 'rxjs/operators';

interface IData {
  data: number;
  emitExtraVal: boolean;
}

class obsData implements IData {
  constructor(data: number) {
    this.data = data;
    this.emitExtraVal = false;
  }
  public data: number;
  public emitExtraVal: boolean;

}

class extraData implements IData {
  constructor(data: number) {
    this.data = data;
    this.emitExtraVal = true;
  }

  public data: number;
  public emitExtraVal: boolean;
}
const sourceOne = of(new obsData(1),new obsData(2),new obsData(3));
/*const finalSource = sourceOne.pipe(
  map((sData) => <IData>new extraData(sData.data)),
  map((sData) => sData)
);*/
const finalSource = sourceOne.pipe(
  mergeMap((sData) => concat(of(<IData>new extraData(sData.data), of(sData))))
);
const subscribe = finalSource.subscribe(val => console.log('Data:' + val.emitExtraVal));
```

What I want to do is output an instance of extraData with the number in obsData followed by the obsData I just took in from the source.  This is not the exact scenario I am attempting but it demonstrates the core of what I'm trying to do which is to create an extra output followed by another output, both of which rely on the a single source input.

**This updated example of the problem is based on comments, however this example won't run because the syntax is not correct**

This produces the following error:

You provided 'function (source) { return source.lift.call(concat_1.concat.apply(void 0, [source].concat(observables))); }' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

**---Update---**
Here is the final answer that works thanks to the responses.  The main problem I was having was that you can import concat from rxjs/operators or rxjs.  You MUST import it from rxjs if you are using it in the pipe command.

```
// RxJS v6+
import { of, fromEvent, combineLatest, concat } from 'rxjs';
import { startWith, scan, tap, mergeMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

interface IData {
  data: number;
  emitExtraVal: boolean;
}

class obsData implements IData {
  constructor(data: number) {
    this.data = data;
    this.emitExtraVal = false;
  }
  public data: number;
  public emitExtraVal: boolean;

}

class extraData implements IData {
  constructor(data: number) {
    this.data = data;
    this.emitExtraVal = true;
  }

  public data: number;
  public emitExtraVal: boolean;
}
const sourceOne = of(new obsData(1),new obsData(2),new obsData(3));

const finalSource = sourceOne.pipe(
  mergeMap((sData) => concat(of(<IData>new extraData(sData.data), <IData>sData)))
);
const subscribe = finalSource.subscribe(val => console.log('Data:' + val.emitExtraVal));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> create an extra output followed by another output, both of which rely on the a single source input.

In my example *dataItem* is the "single source input" which is transformed to Observable of it elements using `from` operator. And later  you can use [flattening operators](https://blog.angularindepth.com/switchmap-bugs-b6de69155524) (like [mergeMap](http://rxmarbles.com/#mergeMap) or [concatMap](http://rxmarbles.com/#concatMap) depending on the requirements) to "flatten" all of this Observables into a single one. See the example:

```js
const { Observable, of, from, concat } = rxjs; // = require("rxjs")
const { mergeMap } = rxjs.operators; // = require("rxjs/operators")

const complexAjaxCall = id => of(`${id}-from-ajax`);

const ids = [1, 2, 3];

from(ids).pipe(
  mergeMap(id => concat(
    complexAjaxCall(id),
    of(id)
  )),
).subscribe(e => console.log(e));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.2.2/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think this is close to what I want the only problem is in my more complex scenario I am not just working with static values.  In your from, what if you needed to make a call out to some api which returned an observable and you needed the return of that to add another value.  The main difference between your example and mine is that my "new data" comes from an outside source not the incoming source.  Are you able to take my example and make that work?

Comment: I thought concat always had to be in pipe command.  That might be what I'm looking for!  I will report back.

Comment: I get this error when I run your example: Error: You provided 'function (source) { return source.lift.call(concat_1.concat.apply(void 0, [source].concat(observables))); }' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

This is something similar to error I get when I try to do what I'm doing.

Comment: Without seeing your changes I can't help.
You should probably edit or create separated question with reproducible code example (preferably runnable/editable online)

Comment: @ChrisHolt Make sure you import `concat` from `rxjs` and not from `rxjs/operators`

Comment: Concat seems to mess up the return values.  Here is complete "runnable" example (I was running it on StackBlitz).  It won't actually run because of the problems I told you about with your syntax.  [Edited original example]

Comment: @OlesSavluk I see your example works when I run the code snippet but it just does not work in typescript or it doesn't work when not dealing with primitives.  Maybe this means the Typescript typings are wrong for rxjs 6.2.2.I am still at a roadblock either way.

Comment: @m1ch4ls that solved the problem!!!  It now works!!  I will post the actual final answer.